# Picture: Stuck Screen (multiple colors) While Installing Any Distro

Tags: system-installation, graphics, uefi

I have Windows 8 installed on this machine, but suddenly wanted to switch to Ubuntu. I have tried installing all Ubuntu flavors (Xubuntu, Lubuntu... etc.) and for hours now I have been getting this screen. I booted from a USB drive, tried different software that make USB bootable (thinking one of them is faulty), tried x86 and x64, tried different USB drives, messed a little bit with my BIOS settings, but I keep getting the problem. I have tried to turn off UEFI, secure boot (both of which do not exist on this PC, since it does not use them).

[image: Picture of garbled graphics]

Comment: Can you still see a boot menu before the garbled graphics appear, where you can choose to try or install Ubuntu amongst others? What's the last “good” thing you see on the screen?

Comment: The logo and being able to choose advanced options except my keyboard doesn't work in that stage, and I tried two.

Answer (score 0):

The boot menu offers a low graphics mode and even a text mode installer in case there's no working graphics driver included with the installation medium. It would be crucial to get your keyboard working so you can select the right mode.

The issue is usually a BIOS setting for “legacy“ USB devices, which you can read about in the manual of your computer/mainboard.
Investigate that issue on the internet, in particular the forums of your computer or mainboard manufacturer.
AskUbuntu should have a bunch of related issues as well. Often just playing around with the few different USB options can solve the issue.
Alternatively try a PS/2 keyboard, if you computer still has such a connector; USB keyboards often come with PS/2 adapters.